# Помогите разобраться в чем ошибка (и есть ли она вообще)

Tags: linux, c, valgrind

имеется вот такой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LENGHT 1001

int main (void)
{
    FILE *input = NULL;
    FILE *output = NULL;

    char *p = malloc (LENGHT * sizeof *p);
    char *t = malloc (LENGHT * sizeof *t);

    char *s = NULL;

    int arr [LENGHT] = { 0 };
    int counter = 0;

    if ((input = fopen ("input.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf ("ERROR of open file input.txt\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fgets (p, LENGHT, input);
    fgets (t, LENGHT, input);

    p = realloc (p, strlen (p) * sizeof *p);
    p [strlen (p) - 1] = '\0';
    t = realloc (t, strlen (t) * sizeof *t);
    t [strlen (t) - 1] = '\0';

    if (fclose (input) != 0) {
        printf ("ERROR of exit from file input.txt\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    s = t;
    for (int i = 0;; ++i) {
        s = strstr (s, p);
        if (s) {
            arr [i] = s - t + 1;
            counter++;
            s++;
        }
        else
            break;
    }

    if ((output = fopen ("output.txt", "w")) == NULL) {
        printf ("ERROR of open file output.txt\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fprintf (output, "%i\n", counter);
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; ++i) {
        fprintf (output, "%i ", arr [i]);
    }

    if (fclose (output) != 0) {
        printf ("ERROR of exit from file output.txt\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    free (p);
    free (t);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Программа выдает количество вхождений в строку искомой подстроки. Все работает, но когда тестировал на возможные ошибки в `valgrind` меня обеспокоил такой вывод `valgrind`-а:

```
==5331== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==5331== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==5331== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==5331== Command: ./serch
==5331== 
==5331== Invalid read of size 1
==5331==    at 0x4C30F74: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5331==    by 0x400983: main (naive_serch.c:31)
==5331==  Address 0x5205b54 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==5331==    at 0x4C2FD5F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5331==    by 0x40096B: main (naive_serch.c:30)
==5331== 
==5331== Invalid read of size 1
==5331==    at 0x4C30F74: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5331==    by 0x4009D4: main (naive_serch.c:33)
==5331==  Address 0x5205ba8 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==5331==    at 0x4C2FD5F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5331==    by 0x4009BC: main (naive_serch.c:32)
==5331== 
==5331== 
==5331== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5331==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5331==   total heap usage: 8 allocs, 8 frees, 11,310 bytes allocated
==5331== 
==5331== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==5331== 
==5331== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5331== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, зачем сюда вообще притянуто динамическое выделение памяти, если там же рядом в коде массив `arr` того же размера объявляется локально... И не LENGHT, а LENGTH.

Comment: Код еще не доработан, ну а инглиш я знаю плохо - в опечатке ничего удивительного.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот это

```
p = realloc (p, strlen (p) * sizeof *p);
```

уже оставляет "за бортом" нулевой терминатор `'\0'`. После этого вызов `strlen` в

```
p [strlen (p) - 1] = '\0';
```

в поисках нулевого терминатора (которого может уже и не быть) осуществит доступ к "чужой" памяти.

Непонятно откуда вообще берется манера вызывать "тяжелые" функции по нескольку раз. Почему бы не сделать через переменную

```
size_t len = strlen(p);
p = realloc (p, len * sizeof *p);
p [len - 1] = '\0';
```

?

---

Отдельно стоит заметить, что вы безусловно завязываетесь на то, что в конце прочитанных `fgets` строк присутствует символ `'\n'`, который вы и пытаетесь удалить. Но он совсем не обязательно там присутствует. Могло получиться так, что строка в файле оказалась длиннее вашего буфера. Могло получиться так, что последняя строка в файле не имела `'\n'` на конце. Поэтому удаление этого `'\n'` рекомендуется делать только после того, как вы убедились, что он там действительно есть. Популярная идиома для решения этой задачи базируется на `strcspn`

```
  size_t len = strcspn(p, "\n");
  p = realloc (p, (len + 1) * sizeof *p);
  p [len] = '\0';
```

Comment: Строго говоря, и такой вызов `realloc()` - неправильный :)

Comment: проблема на самом деле в том, что автор вопроса верит в то, что strlen может посчитать размер массива выделенного через malloc. И начинается проблема ещё с malloc

Comment: сделал через переменную - действительно помогло. Вот только не совсем понял: что означает "нулевой терминатор"?

Comment: @KoVadim а почему нет? Читаем: "Функция strlen вычисляет количество символов в строке до первого вхождения символа конца строки. При этом символ конца строки не входит в подсчитанное количество символов. " - почему нельзя, объясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: strlen считает до первого нулевого символа. А malloc его не вставляет (и не обязан). Но даже если занулить все, тогда strlen будет возвращать ноль. Если вставить ноль в конец строки, то будет возвращать на 1 меньше, чем ожидаете, но не всегда (в строке случайно может оказаться ноль в середине).

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, потому что вот здесь: `realloc (p, strlen (p) * sizeof *p);` в новую память не переносится завершающий `\0`.

Comment: @KoVadim и.... Вы как бы не подумали, что может мне надо на 1 символ меньше, нежели прочитано? Например мне не нужен символ новой строки, который я строкой ниже меняю на `\0`... Так я опять повторюсь: в чем проблема?

Comment: @KoVadim: Не совсем понял. Автор сначала делает `fgets` и только после этого применяет `strlen` к массиву. Понятно, что контроля за успешностью выполняемых операций в коде нет вообще, но тем не менее...

Comment: да, я это также нашел.

Comment: @AnT, см. дальше - после `fgets()` - `realloc()`, который не переносит `\0`, и результат пихается в `strlen()`.